# Ember-Data reload model with parameters

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to `reload` a model with a parameter? I have overridden `urlForFindRecord` with this code:

```
urlForFindRecord(id, modelName, snapshot) {
  let url = this._super(...arguments);
  let query = Ember.get(snapshot, 'adapterOptions.query');
  if (query) {
    url += '?' + Ember.$.param(query);
  }
  return url;
}
```

This works perfectly when I call `findRecord` like so:

```
store.findRecord('type', 123, { adapterOptions: { query: { foo: 'bar' } } });
```

However, based on a property in another model, I need to reload my model. I can't just call `model.reload()` because I need the query param as part of my URL.

I also tried the following in my `afterModel` hook (because the query param is based on the other model):

```
store.findRecord('type', 123, { reload: true, adapterOptions: { query: { foo: 'bar' } } });
```

But the `reload: true` option doesn't work. There's a [bug in ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3704) preventing the `reload` from working. I tried hacking ember-data to allow it to reload, but despite it calling `scheduleFetch` it won't reload the model from the server.

I am using ember-data 1.13.13 and am unable to move to 2.0 because that requires ember 2.0.

Comment: Did you try doing a `store.queryRecord`? It should update the model you already have.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? Facing the same problem in Ember 2.x